# Use calculated SVG Icon in Quasar

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

In my Quasar app I'm trying to dynamically change an SVG icon. I'm using a `computed` property to return the correct name of the icon.

```
<template>
  <q-icon
    :name="iconName"
  />
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { mdiCheckBold, mdiCloseThick } from '@quasar/extras/mdi-v7'

const iconName = computed(() => {
  if (/* some logic */) return 'mdiCheckBold'
  return 'mdiCloseThick'
})
</script>
```

This doesn't work. In the [docs](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/icon#svg-icons) they say, that when using SVG icons, the icon name has to be bound to `name`. When I directly bind one of the icons to the name, then it works – e.g. `:name="mdiCheckBold"` shows the correct icon.

How can I make this work with `computed`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While reviewing my question, I found out how to do it. For anyone having the same question, simply return the imported component instead of a String.

```
<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { mdiCheckBold, mdiCloseThick } from '@quasar/extras/mdi-v7'

const iconName = computed(() => {
  if (/* some logic */) return mdiCheckBold // Don't return as string
  return mdiCloseThick
})
</script>
```